# Meaning of the particle と in this case

Tags: meaning, particle-と

I was listening to the song 一本の鉛筆 performed by 美空ひばり
When I looked into the lyrics, I was confused by two things.

> 一本の鉛筆が あれば
>   戦争はいやだと 私は書く

What's the meaning of the particle と after 戦争はいやだ in this case?

> 一枚のザラ紙が あれば
>   私は子供が 欲しいと書く
>   一枚のザラ紙が あれば
>   あなたをかえしてと 私は書く

In this case, what`s the difference in the meaning after adding　私は書く in the last sentence, instead of just writing あなたをかえしてと書く ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case と is the quotative particle. It indicates what the person will write.

> 一本の鉛筆が あれば 戦争はいやだ**と** 私は書く
>   If I had a pencil I would write **that** war is horrible.

Compare this with 手紙を書く. This means "I will write a letter", but と would be used to mark what you actually write **in** the letter. This と particle is used with verbs such as 言う, 思う etc. to mark what people say, think etc.

As for why　私は is added in the line you mention, I have no idea. Maybe it makes the lyrics fit the tune better. It doesn't do any harm.

Answer (score 0):

It means **that**. I would write **that** the war is horrible.

Comment: Rather than adding an answer which is the same (but less detailed) as  the previous answer you should consider giving an up-vote to the existing answer.